# Jackson - serialize generic collection to json more compactly

Tags: java, json, jackson

I want to serialise generic collections with Jackson in compact way, such that in output i will get json that looks like

> {genericType : [ {field1:1},{field1:25} ]}

## Example:

I have a PoJo that looks like

```
public class ContainList<SomePojo> {
@JsonTypeInfo(use=Id.NAME, include=As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, property="type")
@JsonSubTypes({
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value=SimplePojo1.class, name="simplePojo11")
    ,@JsonSubTypes.Type(value=SimplePojo2.class, name="simplePojo22")
})    
   public List<SomePojo> list;
}
```

Now when i serialize the object i'm getting something like

```
{
  "list": [
    {
      "simplePojo11": {
        "simplePojo11Field": "privet"
      }
    },
    {
      "simplePojo11": {
        "simplePojo11Field": "poka"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My aim is to get something like

```
{
  "list": 
  { simplePojo11 : [  {"simplePojo11Field": "privet"}, {"simplePojo11Field": "poka"} ] }
}
```

Or without list at all

```
  { simplePojo11111 : [  {"simplePojo111111Field": "privet"}, {"simplePojo111111Field": "poka"} ] }
```

Comment: But `list` is a `List`, isn't it? So why do you want to map it to an object?

Comment: To what end? If you want to make it smaller, output it to a compressed stream -- [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) or [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html). It will be smaller than any of the micro-optimisations that you propose in the question.

Comment: It seems to me more native representation of a list in json that looks like "{elements: [{..},{..},{..}]} rather than "{list: [{element:{..}},{element:{..}},{element:{..}}]}

Comment: It seems to me more native representation of a list in json that looks like "{elements: [{..},{..},{..}]} rather than "{list: [{element:{..}},{element:{..}},{element:{..}}]}